# Is there a replacement for this 22-3/4 bathroom window?

Tags: windows

[image]

having trouble finding a replacement for this window; it's about 22 3/4 inches square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"About" won't do. You need to know the exact, (to less than 1/8") dimensions of the rough opening if you are replacing the window with a new-construction-type window, or the dimensions of the inside of the frame if you are using a "replacement window" that fits in the old frame.

You can get windows custom-made to fit either of those, or you can reduce the opening to suit any stock window made for a smaller opening.

It's normal for windowframes to be smaller than the rough opening to allow for shimming. It's also normal for the "claimed size" to be more than the actual size. Sometimes it's the rough opening size, and the window is several inches smaller - so that might be a "24x24" (so-called) while measuring less than 23x23 - you have to check details in the window catalogs or websites.

This answer may help to understand that better: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/201464/18078

Comment: thanks.  22-3/4 is the inside measurement (the opening inside the house.